# Magento SOAP APIv2 Stopped working after server restart

Tags: php, html, magento

My server shutdown unexpectedly today due to Amazon Spot Instance. I restarted the server, updated the address and cleared the cache in var/cache (If not the updated address won't show).

After which, the SOAP API stopped working. It isn't displaying any error, I just can't connect to it even after I disable the API account. Normally when you visit your API from browser e.g.

http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl
http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/
http://example.com/index.php/api/

You will get some results, e.g. XML file, error, or data but it's **redirecting me straight to the home page** now, so it's obviously not getting data from the API.

Why is it even redirecting me to the home page?

The code to calling API is fine, I'm quite sure, since even when I disable the account, it still doesn't show any error etc. Furthermore there wasn't any modification to the code before the server shutdown.

1. Is there anyway I can restart the web service?
2. Did my clear cache of var/cache screw the API up?

I tried to see what was loaded before it redirects.

Reload the page to get source for: http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason .... I find it quite stupid.

core_config_data - my baseurl is set with www. infront so when you call the API , you will also need the www. infront

Comment: you should add a rewrite for non www urls to www urls! enable mod rewrite and rewrite system in magento, check htaccess file!

Comment: My route 53 actually does that, I think i will double check it out. if not htaccess Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. disabled api module?
2. rewrite via htaccess, vhost or magento system?
3. cms page named api? not very possible but one never knows
4. bad custom code in observer, controller rewrite?